# How to configure Include/Lib directories of VC++ devenv.com command line?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm building a VC++ 9.0 project from command line (using `devenv.com`):

```
devenv.com myproject.sln /Build "Release|Win32"
```

I need to add additional include path to it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up using devenv.com for the same reason. I use msbuild instead.

- Add your include and lib to your project
- launch `vcvarsall.bat`
- call `msbuild.exe`

I have Visual Studio 2010. I created a small batch file that is in my path (because I have many dev environments on my computer).

```
@c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat %*
```

And I actually wrap msbuild.exe with this simple batch file :

```
@for %%i in (*.sln) do @msbuild %%i /v:m /nologo %*
```

With the trailing `%*`, you can add other parameters when needed.

Comment: Where I can get these `setenv.bat` and `msbuild.exe`?

Comment: They are installed along with visual studio. Sorry I don't have my computer with me to give you the exact path. Go at the root of your Visual Studio Installation and type `dir /s /b setenv.bat`. I have a copy of it in my path. `setenv.bat` will add the necessary directories to your path so you can call msbuild directly.

Comment: `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0>dir /s /b setenv.bat` leads to `File Not Found`. I have VS 9.0 professional.

Comment: Sorry @yegor256, my bad : setenv.bat is in the Windows Driver Kit SDK. In Visual Studio is it vcvars.bat

Comment: On Visual Studio 2010, it's vcvarsall.bat